# How to skip some java files from compilation in maven using command line?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am using maven with jenkins. On eclipse the project build works fine. When I use jenkins I get the following error

```
[ERROR] /E:/jenkins/workspace/product/src/test/java/com/new/ftp/FTPTest.java:[102,55] package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind does not exist
```

The options for maven are as follows:

```
mvn clean install -X
```

I want to know if I can pass some arguements to maven to skip that package. I don't want to modify my pom.xml yet .

***P.S -*** The project consists of a main pom.xml which calls other child modules.

Comment: share the imports of your `FTPTest.java` please

Comment: Well I added the following to the maven options.

mvn clean install -X -Dmaven.test.skip=true

It works fine now.

Comment: ... *skip that package*, you never said which package above. Anyway, what worked for you is good. But be absolutely sure before you use that.